# Get a value from XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I want to parse this XML  and get cellphone number

```
<Result>
  <text_message>
    <id>4394</id>
    <message>2</message>
    <time>1373998420</time>
    <message_phone>
      <cellphone>09102805755</cellphone>
    </message_phone>
  </text_message>
</Result>
```

my code is:

```
int Num;
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(sms.InboxCheck(authsms, "1", "1", "0"));
doc.Save(Server.MapPath(".") + "\\xmlfolder\\xmlfile2.xml");
ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath(".") + "\\xmlfolder\\xmlfile2.xml");
Num = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables["text_message"].Rows[0][3].ToString());
Label1.Text= Num.ToString();
```

value of this `Rows[0][3]` is `0`

How can I fetch cellphone number?

Comment: Any particular reason you are trying to read the XML into what appears to be a DataSet and not parse it as an XDocument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about continuing to leverage the `XDocument` class?

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(sms.InboxCheck(authsms, "1", "1", "0"));
var cellphone = doc.Root.Element.Elements("message_phone").First().Element.Value
```

Comment: XDocument don't have such a method .
i mean RootElement method.

Comment: Could simplify line 2 to `var cellphone = doc.Descendents("cellphone").First().Value`

Comment: @JimWooley, yes you are correct, which is why I upvoted the answer by Sam I am as well.

Answer (score 3):

do something like this

```
int num = int.parse(doc.Descendants.("cellphone").Single().Value);
```

or better yet

```
string num = doc.Descendants.("cellphone").Single().Value;
```

Comment: Change it to.. 

string num = doc.Descendants("cellphone").Single().Value;

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Serialization?

You can map your xml to a Data Structure (Class) and read it or/and write to it via `XmlSerializer` or `DataContractSerializer`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `XmlDocument` instead.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("myFile.xml");
XmlNode phone = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Result/text_message/message_phone/cellphone");
string number = phone.InnextText;
```